# how to create several lines plot in r

Tags: r, plot, line

let's say we have `x1=c(6,3,5,4,3,7)` and `x2=c(5,2,1,7,5,2)` , then I want to create a plot like:

[image]

Where X axis is only x1 and x2 and Y axis is the corresponding value. how can I do it in R? thx

Comment: "Where X axis is only x1 and x2 and Y axis is the corresponding value."
What does this mean? It reads like you want the x1 and x2 values on the X axis, so what goes on the Y axis? I think you should give some more info, or rewrite your question.

Comment: @CCD , I mean that the X axis has only two values including x1 and x2. Y axis is the corresponding value of x1 and x2 which create a line between them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
plot(1, 1, xlim = c(1,2),
     ylim = range(c(x1, x2)), type = "n", xaxt = "n")
axis(side = 1, at = 1:2, labels = 1:2)
segments(x0 = 1, y0 = x1, x1 = 2, y1 = x2)
points(x = rep(1, length(x1)), y = x1)
points(x = rep(2, length(x2)), y = x2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

First create an empty plotting surface

```
plot(0,0, xlim=c(0,1), ylim=range(c(0, x1,x2)), type="n", xaxt="n")
axis(side=1, at=c(0,1), labels=c("x1","x2"))
```

Then add draw the segments

```
segments(0, x1, 1, x2)
```

and optionally points

```
points(rep(0, length(x1)), x1);
points(rep(1, length(x2)), x2)
```

If you want to use ggplot, it would make more sense to change your data format though

```
dd <- data.frame(id=seq_along(x1), x1=x1, x2=x2)
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(dd) + geom_segment(aes(y=x1, yend=x2), x=0, xend=1)
```